# 'uuid' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm extending my user model-

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

using Django Rest Framework I have the following serializer -

```
class UserSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    company = serializers.CharField(source='userprofile.company', required=False, allow_null=True)
    is_admin = serializers.CharField(source='userprofile.is_admin', required=False, allow_null=True)
    last_modified = serializers.DateTimeField(source='userprofile.last_modified', required=False, allow_null=True)
    uuid = serializers.CharField(source='userprofile.uuid')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'company', 'is_admin', 'last_modified', 'uuid')

    def create(self, attrs, instance=None):
        """
        Given a dictionary of deserialized field values, either update
        an existing model instance, or create a new model instance.
        """
        if instance is not None:
            instance.email = attrs.get('user.email', instance.user.email)
            instance.password = attrs.get('user.password', instance.user.password)
            return instance

        user = User.objects.create_user(username=attrs.get('username'),
                                        email= attrs.get('email'),
                                        password=attrs.get('password'),
                                        uuid=attrs.get('userprofile.uuid'))
        return AppUser(user=user)
```

When trying to create a new user using the following view -

```
class UserViewSet(APIView):
    """
    List all companies, or create a new company.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        userlist = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(userlist, fields=('username', 'email', 'company', 'last_modified'), many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = {'username': request.data.get('username'),
                'first_name': request.data.get('first_name'),
                'last_name': request.data.get('last_name'),
                'email': request.data.get('email'),
                'uuid': str(uuid.uuid4())}
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print serializer.data
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I get the following error in my traceback -

```
Traceback:
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  466.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  463.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/enterpass/core/views.py" in post
  36.             serializer.save()
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in save
  180.             self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
File "/opt/enterpass/core/serializers.py" in create
  50.                                         uuid=attrs.get('userprofile.uuid'))
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in create_user
  187.                                  **extra_fields)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in _create_user
  180.                           date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
File "/opt/enterpass_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __init__
  480.                 raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/users/
Exception Value: 'uuid' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

How do I get my view to correctly write the value both for the User but also the UserProfile models?

Comment: Please post the extended `User` model you are using.

Comment: @RahulGupta it's there at the top.  My UserProfile model has a OneToOneField to User.

Comment: Where is the `uuid` field defined in `User` model?

Comment: It's defined in the UserProfile model not the User model.  When I save I want it to update both the User Model and the UserProfile Model which it is linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you are passing `uuid` as an argument to [`create_user()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) function.

The default `User` model which you are using does not have a `uuid` field in it. The `create_user()` function accepts the fields which are defined in the `User` model as arguments. So you don't need to pass the `uuid` argument.

`create_user()` signature:

> **create_user(username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields)**
>   The `extra_fields` keyword arguments are passed through to the User’s
>   `__init__` method to allow setting arbitrary fields on a custom User model.

```
def create(self, attrs, instance=None): 
    ...
    # Remove the `uuid` argument from `create_user()` call.
    user = User.objects.create_user(username=attrs.get('username'),
                                email= attrs.get('email'),
                                password=attrs.get('password')) 
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **attrs) # create user profile object
    ...
```

Comment: the question then is do I have to pass a separate `userprofile = UserProfile.objects.create(uuid=attrs.get('uuid')`? ie. how do I tie the two model creations together?

Comment: You will have to create a `UserProfile` object separately in your `create()` function using the `user` created before.

Comment: Also you can instead use `ModelViewSet` in your views as all the code which you written there is done by DRF itself internally.

Comment: The problem I found with `ModelViewSet` is that I don't want to return all fields.  I have a `DynamicFieldsModelSerializer` serializer but in a `ModelViewSet` I'm calling the serializer like `serializer_class = UserSerializer` whereas I need to actually call it like `serializer = UserSerializer(userlist, fields=('username', 'email', 'uuid'))`